# Why do my breadcrumbs see double? and How can I control them? A double question?

Tags: views, panels, breadcrumbs

I have a taxonomy menu that invokes a Panel variant linked to a view that uses the taxonomy term.  The display works fine, but I get a breadcrumb trail that repeats the menu path twice.  I cannot find a setting in the menu, panel or view that offers control of the breadcrumbs, in fact, since this is my first time dealing with breadcrumbs, I discovered I cannot find what controls them at all.  How do I configure breadcrumbs?

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem and find out that theme I was using had breadcrumb override function in template.php which was messing with results.