# Double breadcrumbs with taxonomy menu and taxonomy menu trails

Tags: breadcrumbs, taxonomy-terms

I have an issue similar to the one described in
[Why do my breadcrumbs see double? and How can I control them? A double question?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15044/why-do-my-breadcrumbs-see-double-and-how-can-i-control-them-a-double-question)

With taxonomy menu trails I got the breadcrumb to my node related to the taxonomy working, but now on my view page, when I go deeper than the first level, I start getting double-crumbs.

What should/can I do about it?